# SpringLiquibase errors when running on docker

Tags: spring, docker, liquibase

I'm working with SpringLiquibase using the latest liquibase version 
liquibase-core 3.8.7 and I created a bean

```
 @Bean
    public SpringLiquibase getLiquibase() {
        // Configure Liquibase

        SpringLiquibase liquibase = new SpringLiquibase();
        liquibase.setChangeLog("classpath:db_scripts/db.changelog-master.yaml");
        liquibase.setDataSource(dataSource);
        liquibase.setShouldRun(true);

        return liquibase;
    }
```

and the db.changelog-master.yaml is under resources and looks like that

```
databaseChangeLog:
  - includeAll:
      path: db_changes/
      relativeToChangelogFile: true
```

when I run the application locally it's running good, but when I run it as a docker I get the following error:

```
Caused by: liquibase.exception.ChangeLogParseException: Error parsing classpath:db_scripts/db.changelog-master.yaml
    at liquibase.parser.core.yaml.YamlChangeLogParser.parse(YamlChangeLogParser.java:83)
    at liquibase.Liquibase.getDatabaseChangeLog(Liquibase.java:217)
    at liquibase.Liquibase.update(Liquibase.java:190)
    at liquibase.Liquibase.update(Liquibase.java:179)
    at liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase.performUpdate(SpringLiquibase.java:366)
    at liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase.afterPropertiesSet(SpringLiquibase.java:314)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1855)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1792)
    ... 22 common frames omitted
Caused by: liquibase.exception.SetupException: Could not find directory or directory was empty for includeAll 'db_changes/'
    at liquibase.changelog.DatabaseChangeLog.includeAll(DatabaseChangeLog.java:528)
    at liquibase.changelog.DatabaseChangeLog.handleChildNode(DatabaseChangeLog.java:395)
    at liquibase.changelog.DatabaseChangeLog.load(DatabaseChangeLog.java:305)
    at liquibase.parser.core.yaml.YamlChangeLogParser.parse(YamlChangeLogParser.java:77)
    ... 29 common frames omitted
Caused by: liquibase.exception.SetupException: Could not find directory or directory was empty for includeAll 'db_changes/'
    at liquibase.changelog.DatabaseChangeLog.includeAll(DatabaseChangeLog.java:519)
    ... 32 common frames omitted
```

I know there is a bug 
https://liquibase.jira.com/browse/CORE-2863 but it doesn't talk about docker.
so I'm not sure it's related.

any ideas?

Comment: so path to your `db_changes/` is `db_scripts/db_changes/` ? If so put to changelog path `db_scripts/db_changes/` and make `relativeToChangelogFile=false`

Comment: your idea didn't work.
aused by: liquibase.exception.SetupException: Could not find directory or directory was empty for includeAll 'db_scripts/db_changes/'
 at liquibase.changelog.DatabaseChangeLog.includeAll(DatabaseChangeLog.java:519)

Comment: can you provide example on github to look into sources?